# Wordpress post pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

How to display 10 post in home page and also show pagination below? Is it possible to use `have_post()` ?

```
 <?php if (have_posts()):
                    $incr=1;
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="postindex <?php echo (($incr%2==0)?'even':'odd') ?>" id="post-<?php echo $incr ?>">
                            <div class="postIncr"><?php echo $incr ?></div><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>
                            <div class="clear-float"></div>
                            <?php strip_tags(the_excerpt(__('Readmore ?')));?>
                        </div>
                    <?php $incr++; endwhile;    
endif ?>
```

This is my coding, I have installed wp_paginate, so how can I use there, I want to show 6 post on a page
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't downvote. If you know the answer then write your answer here. There is no meaning to downvote without any answer or feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Pagination Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/). You just need to change css.

Comment: Please provide some more option.

Comment: Did you install plugin? If yes then pagination need to already be visible, if not then go to Plugin page, click add new and in search box insert **wp paginate**, press search and install first plugin. After instalation click activate.